# ASP NET LinkButton - Inner Controls Removed

Tags: asp.net

We have the follow repeater construct on our home page:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repShortcuts" OnItemDataBound="repShortcuts_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkShortcut" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("LinkWithTab") %>' Text="" ViewStateMode="Enabled" Style="text-decoration: none;">
            <div style="margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px; height: 90px; display: inline-block; white-space: normal; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;">
                <asp:Image
                    runat="server"
                    ID="imgShortcut"
                    ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("./Icons/{0}{1}",Session["DetailsBoxTextColour"].ToString().ToLower() == "black" ? "d" : "", Eval("ParentIcon")) %>'
                    CssClass="MenuImage"
                    Style="margin-bottom: 0px;"
                />
                <asp:Label
                    runat="server"
                    ID="lblShortcut"
                    Text='<%# Eval("DisplayName") %>'
                    CssClass="MenuText"
                    Style="font-size: small; overflow: hidden; width: 110px; white-space: pre-line; text-wrap: normal; display: inline-block;"
                ></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblEmptyData" runat="server" CssClass="DetailsBoxSettingLabel MarginTop5" Text="You currently have no shortcuts." Visible="false" />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

When viewing the page (GET):

On server A (live) the inner controls are rendered as expected (this is an image and some text). Also works on all our dev machines.

On server B (uat) and some user machines which have the application installed, the inner controls are removed and we are just left with the anchor tag for the linkbutton.

This seems to be related to Microsoft Connect issue 718810 which is nowhere to be found now. Completely lost as to what's going on here. Same code, same server setup essentially.

Comment: On UAT, open the browser debug tools, go to the Network tab and refresh the page. Are there any errors for the images that are requested ? One possibility is that the images are not on the UAT server in the correct place.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I've checked and the images are there but I also would have thought that we'd get the markup for the image tag in the HTML generated - the image just wouldn't be valid. To confirm it's the complete inner markup which is not generated on UAT - almost as if on that server the LinkButton control has deleted the inner controls defined in the aspx page itself.

Comment: Interestingly we have another error on a gridview control where the inner markup for a label has been removed:

<asp:Label ID="lblInputDate_from" runat="server">                                                                                                
   <%# Eval("Datefrom") %>                                                                                           </asp:Label>

In this case the label shows no text on UAT but works fine on Live.

Comment: Possibly related... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623393/

Comment: This was related to an another function in the code so not a problem with framework.